# Substitution into Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, substitution

I have the equation:

$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{\tau}}-(r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{Z}}-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{Z}^2}=0$

I'm than asked to change the coordinates to $y=Z + (r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau$ when this is done it results in the heat equation:

$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{\tau}}=\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{y}^2}$

I'm not sure how to go about this. Does the change of coordinates use the same method as a substitution?

Hence using the chain rule:

$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{Z}}=\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{Z}}$

$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{Z}}=\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau$

and

$\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{Z}^2}=\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{Z}}(\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{Z}})$

$\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{Z}^2}=(\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{y}^2}.(\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{Z}})^2+\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.\frac{\partial^2{y}}{\partial{Z}^2})$

$\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{Z}^2}=(\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{y}^2}.((r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau)^2+\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.0)$

subbing in

$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{\tau}}-(r-\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2)\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}.(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau-\frac{\partial^2{D}}{\partial{y}^2}.((r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau)^2=0$

clearly this doesn't give the desired result.

Can anyone explain how to do this correctly?

I'm not even sure I'm using the correct method.

Comment: $$\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{Z}}=\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{Z}}\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}+\frac{\partial{y}}{\partial{\tau}}\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}=\Big(1+r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}\Big)\frac{\partial{D}}{\partial{y}}$$ isn't it?

Comment: Why does the $\tau$ disappear?